# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver on Ubuntu running jar file

Tags: java, ubuntu, jdbc, ubuntu-12.04

I've created little java application that connects to MySQL. I tested it on my local machine and it worked fine. I exported the Java project to Runnable jar file using Eclipse.

I copied the jar file on my server running Ubuntu 12.04 and ran it with the command

```
java -jar server.jar
```

and it threw the error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
```

I understand that this class could not be found on the server. Then - how can I install this driver?

I have everything in folder /tvplan/
there's a server.jar file that is exported as Runnable jar
also there is a folder lib which holds mysql-connector-java.jar and libintl.jar (both I got using 
    sudo apt-get install libmysql-java
, but when I run 
    java -cp "lib/mysql-connector-java.jar;server.jar" Server
bt it throws me an error
    Error: Could not find or load main class Server

Comment: Copying the Mysql JDBC jar to the same directory should work for you.

Comment: It is a runnable jar file, don't see how that can be a web application @LuiggiMendoza.

Comment: @Marcelo didn't see the `java -jar ...` command

Answer (score 1):

If you use a jar file then the jar file must include a class-path line in the manifest. The line specifies the libraries/class to include. Your jar either does not do this at all, or has a wrong link.

Open the jar with an unzip program and open the manifest file to see which issue it is.

I suspect you used Eclipse's option to include the libraries (but not extract or repackage them) and therefor they're placed in a folder outside of the jar file, and that folder is not present on the linux machine. There are 3 options for the Eclipse exporter regarding library handling, the first 2 will produce a self contained Jar. The first option will break the license agreement on the mysql connector, but the 2nd will not. The 3rd will put the libraries in a folder that you need to copy along with the jar you made.

Comment: I cannot open the jar file with Archive utility (I'm on MacOS). And when I exported with Eclipse, there were only the jar file, no filders no nothing. Can you please provide step by step solution?

Comment: Either 1) Get "the unarchiver" from the app store to unarchive the jar file. Then see which issue you're having, or 2) Export the jar file using the 1st option for library handling.

Answer (score -1):

Use the `cp` option of `java` to put the MySQL jdbc driver on the classpath, for instance:

> java -cp ".;lib/mysql-connector-java-*version*-bin.jar;server.jar" *package.Server*

if your jdbc driver resides under `lib` directory and replace *package.Server* with the fully qualified name of your main class.

Comment: -cp does not work with -jar.

Comment: So this should work? It sais Error: Could not find or load main class package.Server

Comment: @LokoTerrorita as I mentioned in the answer, you have to replace _package.Server_ with your main class (which contains the main method)

Comment: Hmm, it's funny, but I cannot find the package name. The files all are in (default package), but I don't remember what name does the whole package have. How can I find it?

Comment: @LokoTerrorita if you put everything in (default package) then there is no package name, just use the name of the class. Btw, using default packages in java is a bad practice, you should avoid it

Comment: Ok, I typed java -cp ".;/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar;server.jar" Server (Server.java is my main class for the app) and the mysql.jar and mysql-connector-jave.jar ar in /usr/share/java folder, but still it says Error: Could not find or load main class Server

Comment: @LokoTerrorita `server.jar` is the jar of your application, be sure it's specified properly

Comment: jup server.jar is the jar file, Server.java is the main class, and now mysql-connector-java.jar is located in the folder lib in the same folder where is the server.jar, but still the command java -cp ".;lib/mysql-connector-java.jar;server.jar" Server says Could not find or load main class server.jar